# Is there a way to restrict parallel execution of the same function in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, runtime

**Context:** I have a function which is triggered by the onchange() trigger of Google Apps Script on my main google sheet (Master Sheet). The check() function is triggered from the onchange() function to check if the edited cell is green in color if it is, then this function finds out the last row of a different sheet (Supplier Sheet) and then pastes the row from the master sheet after the last row of the supplier sheet.

**Problem:** The problem I'm facing is if I add green color to two cells of different row at the same time, now the function will be triggered for these both rows simultaneously, and in both these executions the row number of last row of the supplier sheet will be stored (say for example 7th row is the last filled row). Now both these executions will write data onto the 8th row, meaning one execution will overwrite the other (on row 8 as per the example).

**My Requirement:** I want this function to be run only once at a given time to avoid this issue and the other executions should be queued up, is there a way I can do this? Or suggest me a different solution if possible.

**What I Tried:**
I tried to put in an if condition right before the function pastes the data to check if the row is blank, and in case the row is not empty, it will add 1 to the row number. This will reduce the chance of overwriting however it is still possible that both the concurrently running functions are on the if condition at the same time and so there will be overwriting even if that will be rare.

Other issue with this approach is simultaneous execution of this function 3 or more rows from master sheet. In this case let's say the last row of supplier sheet is 7, then one execution will write on row number 8, the other two executions will add 1 to tow number as the if condition will see that the 8th row is not empty, so both these remaining 2 simultaneous executions will try to paste the data on row 9 of supplier sheet, meaning one will overwrite the other, so the issue persists.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, how about using [LockService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)? [Refs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+LockService) If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: " if I add green color to two cells of different row at the same time, now the function will be triggered for these both rows simultaneously" You mean as in selecting a range and applying the color to those different cells at the same time? or as in 2 users selecting a different cell and applying the color at the same time? Apologize for the confusion, English is not my first language

Comment: @MatiasCG It can be either of those, the only thing I want is the same function must not run concurrently at a given time, I will try using Lock Service as mentioned by @ Tanaike , I think that might work, however I'm still open to other suggestions or solutions, if any